# Can the windows metro style layout be reproduced with flexboxes?

Tags: css, microsoft-metro, flexbox

[image]

Can this type of layout be implemented using non-nested flex boxes?

I know that `flex-wrap` will make the boxes go on the next line if they don't fit, but how can I also get boxes with variable height like in the screenshot above, without nesting more flex boxes?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, with some normal CSS float based grids, it is possible to create boxy layouts like these.
For example see [this example](http://www.paulund.co.uk/playground/demo/metro-grid/) and [how the author did it](http://www.paulund.co.uk/create-interactive-grid-dashboard).

Also MS proposed a standard called "[CSS Grid Layout](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-grid-layout-20120322/)" to the W3C which is described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ie/hh673533%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It allows to create such layouts without flexbox support. It never got adopted outside IE but if you only need to care about IE, you can use it.